# java jbox2d swing draw and move shape

Tags: java, swing, draw, shapes, jbox2d

How do I draw a shape and then move with jbox2D and swing ?

I can draw it but when I move, the old shape is displayed.

thank you

```
public class DrawShape extends DebugDraw {
private Graphics graphics;

    public DrawShape(Graphics graphics) {
        super(new OBBViewportTransform());          
        this.graphics = graphics;
    }

    public void drawCircle(Vec2 center, float radius, Color3f color) {
        graphics.fillOval((int) (center.x - (radius / 2)), (int) (center.y - (radius / 2)), (int) radius, (int) radius);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your drawing is likely in error. A class should almost never have a Graphics field.
2. I assume that you're drawing in one of the painting methods, either `paint(Graphics g)` (don't do this), or `paintComponent(Graphics g)` in a JComponent-derived class (yes, use this one). If so, you are not likely calling the super method from within this method override.

Comment: ok thank you, I removed the graphic field, I used static methods.
But why are forms she display?

Comment: @user2706812: removing the Graphics field is good. Using static methods is not good. I don't understand your question, `"But why are forms she display?"` as it does not parse well as an English question. Please re-write it, please show more code and information as an edit to your question above.

Comment: i'm sorry for english. When my circle is moving, previous circles are not deleted.

Comment: @user2706812: please look at point 2 in my answer above. Please provide more information and code showing how you're drawing things.

Comment: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/900409Sanstitre.png

Comment: @user2706812: no, not an image. **Again**, we need code please and an improved more informative question!